# Appending environmental variables from one batch file to another

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

This is a line of code from a batch file I'm working on.

```
echo %systemroot% >> untitled.bat
```

It's job is to append the text `%systemroot%` to another batch file called *untitled.bat*.
When I open the untitled.bat file with notepad to view the code it reads `C:\Windows`.
This makes sense because that is my `%systemroot%` but my problem is that I want the code to be written to the untitled.bat file as `%systemroot%` not `C:\Windows`.

Does anyone know how (if at all) this is possible?

Comment: Did you try using quotes, i.e. `echo "%systemroot%" >> untitled.bat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code works for me:

```
echo %%systemroot%% >> untitled.bat
```